# How can I manage the scope problem in Python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
x = 1


def increaseX(number):
    x += number


increaseX(2)
print(x)
```

I want to increase a glob variable via the function `increaseX`, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: put `global x`  in the function. But note this is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`global` keyword is what you need:

```py
x = 1

def increaseX(number):
    global x
    x += number

increaseX(2)
print(x)
```

Otherwise, Python tries to find `x` in local namespace because of `+=` (something like `x = x + number`) and because in the right hand side of the assignment there is no `x` defined, you will get :

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works, but I don't feel this is the best way
x = 1

```
def increaseX(number):
    global x
    x += number


increaseX(2)
print(x)
```